# XML Processing in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to get data from xmlsoccer.com Basically I want to read the data and then process the xml and then organize all the data into a database. The site suggest this code below. However will someone please explain to me what will the variable $result have inside as when I use `echo $result;` nothing is printed. And I need the xml in it to be processed. I'm new to all this so please explain to me the easy way. Thanks all :)

```
include("XMLSoccer.php");
try{
    $soccer=new XMLSoccer("your_api_key");
    $soccer->setServiceUrl("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx");
    $result=$soccer->GetFixturesByDateIntervalAndLeague(array("league"=>3,"startDateString"=>"2014-08-01 00:00","endDateString"=>"2014-09-30 00:00"));
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(XMLSoccerException $e){
    echo "XMLSoccerException: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You said when you use `echo $result` there is nothing. So what is the result of var_dump? At least `false` I'd presume?

Comment: Result of 'echo $result'  http://oi67.tinypic.com/hs5dlj.jpg

Comment: So you _are_ getting the XML.  You can't just `echo` that to the screen and expect it to automatically be formatted nicely for you. Also, there's a difference between `var_dump` and `echo`. They are not interchangeable, and you should make sure you are properly stating which you are using.

Comment: Yes sure, but rather than just seeing it I want to process it to organize the data, I want someone to explain to me how it can be done please :)

Comment: You haven't said what exactly it is you want to do with the data, so there's no way we could tell you _how_ to do it.  "Process" could mean any number of things.

Comment: I want this : for example <yellowcards>2</yellowcards> . The number 2 will be entered in the database in the yellowcards field.

Comment: If the code you posted above is the only code that you have, then you're a long way off from doing that and aren't yet at the point where this is the appropriate place to look for help. If you actually have more code that is relevant, then you should show it.

Comment: Pls write us what var_dump($result) is giving.

Comment: @Vincent. There's a link with a screenshot since the result is quite long. Basically its like the xml I think. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for trying to help me .Will try to dig deeper or in the meantime maybe someone will know a solution.

Comment: Ok so the link is not the echo but the var_dump.

Comment: exactly the echo gives out a blank page

Comment: But Justin ... SO is not a place where you ask people to do the work for you... You know the data is XML formatted. And you want to extract some data from it... So why wouldn't you start by Google and search for xml manipulation in php...

Comment: I tried vincent but their xml are all in a file which they can use fopen etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  You have the XML as an XML object.

### Echo

You cannot echo an object or array.  You must first convert it to a string.

I usually do assign what I want to see to a variable name $show then echo $show where appropriate.

```
$show = var_export($result,true);
```

Or in place of the echo

```
var_export($result,false);
```

The 2nd parameter (true/false) is for whether you want to assign it to a variable or echo it immediately.

### XML to Array

I prefer to convert an object to an array for simplicity.  And I have tools to analyze an array and give me the proper syntax for each data element.

Try this code:
The XML2array converts the object to an array.

```
XML2array($result,$res);
var_export($res);
```

Add this function that converts a the XML object to an array.

```
function XML2array($obj, &$result) { 
  $data = $obj;
  if (is_object($data)) {
    $data = get_object_vars($data);
  }
  if (is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $res = null;
      XML2array($value, $res);
      if (($key == '@attributes') && ($key)) {
        $result = $res;
      } else {
        $result[$key] = $res;
      }
    }
  } else {
    $result = $data;
  }
}
```

If you want to store as JSON add this code:

```
file_put_contents('soccer.jsn',json_encode($res));
```

### UPDATE

It took them a few hours but I finally got an API key.
The above code is no longer untested.

Your query matched 46 records (0-45)

The syntax of the data is:
Where $key = 0 to 45

### Result Syntax

```
$res['Match'][$key]['Id']
$res['Match'][$key]['Date']
$res['Match'][$key]['League']
$res['Match'][$key]['Round']
$res['Match'][$key]['HomeTeam']
$res['Match'][$key]['HomeTeam_Id']
$res['Match'][$key]['HomeGoals']
$res['Match'][$key]['AwayTeam']
$res['Match'][$key]['AwayTeam_Id']
$res['Match'][$key]['AwayGoals']
$res['Match'][$key]['Time']
$res['Match'][$key]['Location']
$res['Match'][$key]['HomeTeamYellowCardDetails']
$res['Match'][$key]['AwayTeamYellowCardDetails']
$res['Match'][$key]['HomeTeamRedCardDetails'] 
$res['Match'][$key]['AwayTeamRedCardDetails']
```

The ['Match'] is of no use so I would eliminate it with this:

```
$res = $res['Match'];
```

The new syntax for `$res['Match'][$key]['Id']`  becomes `$res[$key]['Id']`

### Print Routine

Then to print each record:

```
foreach ($res as $key => $array){
  $datetime = date('F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime($res[$key]['Date'] ));
  echo "<p>$key) id:" . $res[$key]['Id'] . ', Date Time:' . "$datetime, League:" . $res[$key]['League'] . ', Round:' . $res[$key]['Round'] . '<br/>Home Team: ' . $res[$key]['HomeTeam'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['HomeTeam_Id'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['HomeGoals'] . '<br/>Away Team: ' . $res[$key]['AwayTeam'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['AwayTeam_Id'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['AwayGoals'] . '<br/>' . $res[$key]['Time'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['Location'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['HomeTeamYellowCardDetails'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['AwayTeamYellowCardDetails'] . ', ' . $res[$key]['HomeTeamRedCardDetails'] . ', ' .$res[$key]['AwayTeamRedCardDetails'] . "<p>\n";
}
```

### Link to Example Working XML App

[Link to Working XML App](http://ispeedlink.com/so/xmlsoccer/)

### Output Example

0) id:333305, Date Time:September 27, 2014, 10:00 am, League:Scottish Premier League, Round:8
Home Team: Ross County, 360, 2
Away Team: Dundee FC, 522, 1
Finished, Victoria Park, 61': Graham Carey;, 90': Greg Stewart;88': Martin Boyle;, ,

1) id:333304, Date Time:September 27, 2014, 10:00 am, League:Scottish Premier League, Round:8
Home Team: Motherwell, 47, 0
Away Team: Hamilton, 228, 4
Finished, Fir Park Stadium, 65': Jack Leitch;61': Fraser Kerr;19': Zaine Francis-Angol;14': Paul Lawson;2': Stephen McManus;, 58': Grant Gillespie;, ,

2) id:333303, Date Time:September 27, 2014, 10:00 am, League:Scottish Premier League, Round:8
Home Team: Kilmarnock, 52, 3
Away Team: Partick, 561, 0
Finished, Rugby Park, , 81': Kris Doolan;72': Jake Carroll;63': Aaron Muirhead;, ,

3) id:333302, Date Time:September 27, 2014, 10:00 am, League:Scottish Premier League, Round:8
Home Team: Dundee United, 51, 2
Away Team: St Johnstone, 46, 0
Finished, Tannadice Park, 90': Callum Morris;66': Nadir Ciftci;, 79': David Wotherspoon;, ,

### $res Array Example

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '333305',
    'Date' => '2014-09-27T14:00:00+00:00',
    'League' => 'Scottish Premier League',
    'Round' => '8',
    'HomeTeam' => 'Ross County',
    'HomeTeam_Id' => '360',
    'HomeGoals' => '2',
    'AwayTeam' => 'Dundee FC',
    'AwayTeam_Id' => '522',
    'AwayGoals' => '1',
    'Time' => 'Finished',
    'Location' => 'Victoria Park',
    'HomeTeamYellowCardDetails' => '61\': Graham Carey;',
    'AwayTeamYellowCardDetails' => '90\': Greg Stewart;88\': Martin Boyle;',
    'HomeTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
    'AwayTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '333304',
    'Date' => '2014-09-27T14:00:00+00:00',
    'League' => 'Scottish Premier League',
    'Round' => '8',
    'HomeTeam' => 'Motherwell',
    'HomeTeam_Id' => '47',
    'HomeGoals' => '0',
    'AwayTeam' => 'Hamilton',
    'AwayTeam_Id' => '228',
    'AwayGoals' => '4',
    'Time' => 'Finished',
    'Location' => 'Fir Park Stadium',
    'HomeTeamYellowCardDetails' => '65\': Jack Leitch;61\': Fraser Kerr;19\': Zaine Francis-Angol;14\': Paul Lawson;2\': Stephen McManus;',
    'AwayTeamYellowCardDetails' => '58\': Grant Gillespie;',
    'HomeTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
    'AwayTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '333303',
    'Date' => '2014-09-27T14:00:00+00:00',
    'League' => 'Scottish Premier League',
    'Round' => '8',
    'HomeTeam' => 'Kilmarnock',
    'HomeTeam_Id' => '52',
    'HomeGoals' => '3',
    'AwayTeam' => 'Partick',
    'AwayTeam_Id' => '561',
    'AwayGoals' => '0',
    'Time' => 'Finished',
    'Location' => 'Rugby Park',
    'HomeTeamYellowCardDetails' => NULL,
    'AwayTeamYellowCardDetails' => '81\': Kris Doolan;72\': Jake Carroll;63\': Aaron Muirhead;',
    'HomeTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
    'AwayTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '333302',
    'Date' => '2014-09-27T14:00:00+00:00',
    'League' => 'Scottish Premier League',
    'Round' => '8',
    'HomeTeam' => 'Dundee United',
    'HomeTeam_Id' => '51',
    'HomeGoals' => '2',
    'AwayTeam' => 'St Johnstone',
    'AwayTeam_Id' => '46',
    'AwayGoals' => '0',
    'Time' => 'Finished',
    'Location' => 'Tannadice Park',
    'HomeTeamYellowCardDetails' => '90\': Callum Morris;66\': Nadir Ciftci;',
    'AwayTeamYellowCardDetails' => '79\': David Wotherspoon;',
    'HomeTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
    'AwayTeamRedCardDetails' => NULL,
  ),
```

### Final Code

```
$soccer=new XMLSoccer("your_api_key");
$soccer->setServiceUrl("http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx");
$result=$soccer->GetFixturesByDateIntervalAndLeague(array("league"=>3,"startDateString"=>"2014-08-01 00:00","endDateString"=>"2014-09-30 00:00"));
XML2array($result,$res);
$res = $res['Match'];
foreach ($res as $key => $array){
  $datetime = date('F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime($array['Date'] ));
  echo "<p>$key) id:" .$array['Id'] . ', Date Time:' . "$datetime, League:" .$array['League'] . ', Round:' .$array['Round'] . '<br/>Home Team: ' .$array['HomeTeam'] . ', ' .$array['HomeTeam_Id'] . ', ' .$array['HomeGoals'] . '<br/>Away Team: ' .$array['AwayTeam'] . ', ' .$array['AwayTeam_Id'] . ', ' .$array['AwayGoals'] . '<br/>' .$array['Time'] . ', ' .$array['Location'] . ', ' .$array['HomeTeamYellowCardDetails'] . ', ' .$array['AwayTeamYellowCardDetails'] . ', ' .$array['HomeTeamRedCardDetails'] . ', ' .$res[$key]['AwayTeamRedCardDetails'] . "<p>\n";
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export($res);
echo '<pre>';
file_put_contents('soccer.jsn',json_encode($res));
}
catch(XMLSoccerException $e){
    echo "XMLSoccerException: ".$e->getMessage();
}
function XML2array($obj, &$result) { 
  $data = $obj;
  if (is_object($data)) {
    $data = get_object_vars($data);
  }
  if (is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $res = null;
      XML2array($value, $res);
      if (($key == '@attributes') && ($key)) {
        $result = $res;
      } else {
        $result[$key] = $res;
      }
    }
  } else {
    $result = $data;
  }
}
```